# Flutter error "Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1"

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, build.gradle, gradle-task

I'm using windows 10 64-bit system
I'm running default flutter project code on my real device ( Samsung A30)
and I also enabled USB debugging on my phone.
All android versions are installed in my Android Studio. I also updated Flutter SDK and my Gradle is also updated.
I also gave path of flutter sdk in my environment variables.
Still, I'm facing error while running flutter project like

> "Finished with error:gradle task assembledebug failed with exit code
>   -1".

I even uninstalled Android Studio, Dart and removed Flutter and again installed everything, but still getting the same error. VS Code is also giving same error.
What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Try to change the flutter channel to master or beta if it's already in master.

Answer (score -1):

You are not enable in your developer options install via USB.

Comment: Your answer is not making sense right now. Please update it :)